# References about algebraic/differential geometry in French

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry, soft-question

Aside from learning mathematics, I am learning French, so I would like to practise both at the same time if possible. Do you know of any good references about complex/algebraic geometry or differential geometry in French? The mathematics French school is quite important (it still is or it was?) so I guess there should be good references in French.

Thanks.

Comment: I would start by looking at lecture notes from universities (Jussieu/UPMC?) and Grand Schools such as ENS or Polytechnique. E.g, [these ones](http://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/DEA99.pdf) and [those](https://www.math.ens.fr/enseignement/fiche_cours.html?cours=54)?

Comment: Luckily for you,  a great portion of the progress in algebraic geometry in the 20th century was made by French mathematicians. Actually, many algebraic geometrists with no interest in learning French have to read texts in this language anyway. Just grab anything written by Grothendieck, and enjoy yourself.

Comment: The Project Gutenberg [mathematics bookshelf](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Mathematics_%28Bookshelf%29) has a number of works in French (and in German). These might be useful since the mathematical material may be familiar to you, allowing you to focus on language.

Comment: Thanks! One question, out of curiosity: is the mathematics French school loosing relevance? Is French loosing relevance in mathematics?